# Android Studio: app theme different in preview, running device and styles.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, themes

I'm trying to change the theme of an app that I'm trying to develop using Android Studio. Apparently, there are at least two ways to do so: by editing the styles.xml file and by using the button above the preview (for me it's the middle button stating the name of the selected theme).

What I'm witnessing is this: When I try to change the theme by using the button, it will update the preview. When I edit the styles.xml file, neither the button caption nor the preview change. And when I run the application, neither the theme chosen using the button nor the theme specified in the styles.xml file are used.

So for example, I have chosen "Material Dark" using the button and specified Holo Light in styles.xml like so without the two interfering with each other at all:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

And then, when I finally run the app in an emulator, I don't even know the theme (light gray action bar, black text color) that it displays the app in but it's not one that I have specified.

That being said, (almost) every other change I apply to the app in any way using Android Studio is displayed just fine both in the preview and in the emulator. An exception to that rule is the changing of the text color of the elements through the activity's XML file...

I'd appreciate any help, since I'm at my wit's end and also somewhat new to the whole thing.

Thanks! - koala

Answer (score 0):

This is because ide sees no emulator. Emulator always run, but ide could hang up in state "Waiting for target device to come online".

Possible reason - Android API versions mismatch. Check if `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in `Gradle Scripts - build.gradle (Module: app)` correspond device API (also Synch push Synch Project with Gradle Files on a panel). Also low versions (e.g. API 15) result in ide-emulator link failure, inspite of application and device versions match.